# How to push NLP model trained with pytorch in hugging face?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, huggingface-transformers, pytorch-lightning, pytorch-dataloader

I trained fine tune T5 model with my dataset.

Here is my model class

```
class QA_model(pl.LightningModule):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.model=T5ForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained(model_t5,return_dict=True)


  def forward(self,input_ids, attention_mask,labels=None):
    output=self.model(input_ids=input_ids,
                 attention_mask=attention_mask,labels=labels)
    
    return output.loss, output.logits

  def training_step(self,batch,batch_idx):
    input_ids=batch['input_ids']
    attention_mask=batch['attention_mask']
    labels=batch['labels']
    loss,outputs=self.forward(input_ids, attention_mask,labels)
    self.log('train_loss',loss,prog_bar=True,logger=True)
    return loss
  def validation_step(self,batch,batch_idx):
    input_ids=batch['input_ids']
    attention_mask=batch['attention_mask']
    labels=batch['labels']
    loss,outputs=self.forward(input_ids, attention_mask,labels)
    self.log('val_loss',loss,prog_bar=True,logger=True)
    return loss
  def test_step(self,batch,batch_idx):
    input_ids=batch['input_ids']
    attention_mask=batch['attention_mask']
    labels=batch['labels']
    loss,outputs=self.forward(input_ids, attention_mask,labels)
    self.log('test_loss',loss,prog_bar=True,logger=True)
    return loss
  def configure_optimizers(self):
    return AdamW(self.parameters(),lr=0.0001)
```

I initialize my model:

```
my_model=QA_model()

from pytorch_lightning.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
checkpoint_callback=ModelCheckpoint(
    dirpath='checkpoints',
    filename='best-checkpoints',
    save_top_k=1,
    verbose=True,
    monitor='val_loss',
    mode='min'
)
```

from pytorch_lightning.loggers import TensorBoardLogger

```
logger=TensorBoardLogger('training-logs',name='QA_model')
trainer=pl.Trainer(
    logger=logger,
    checkpoint_callback=checkpoint_callback,
    max_epochs=N_EPOCHS,
    gpus=1,
    progress_bar_refresh_rate=30
)
```

and after I trained:

```
trainer.fit(my_model,data_module)
```

As I fine-tuned model, I want to put it in hugging face.
I am using the following command:

```
trainer.save_pretrained("my_account/t5-base-finetuned-legal_data")
trainer.push_to_hub("my_account/t5-base-finetuned-legal_data")
```

but it gives the error:

```
QA_model model does not have save_pretrained/push_to_hub attribute.
```

I am using the following versions:

```
!pip install --quiet transformers==4.1.1
!pip install --quiet pytorch-lightning==1.1.3

!pip install --quiet tokenizers==0.9.4
!pip install --quiet sentencepiece==0.1.94
```

Comment: Which version of `transformers` are you running?

Comment: @dennlinger transformers==4.1.1